# How to set PIDfile when starting FreeSWITCH from the console?

Tags: freeswitch

I know that when starting via systemd, the service unit file allows setting it. For example, [debian/freeswitch-systemd.freeswitch.service](https://freeswitch.org/stash/projects/FS/repos/freeswitch/browse/debian/freeswitch-systemd.freeswitch.service) in v1.8.5):

```
[Service]
; service
Type=forking
PIDFile=/run/freeswitch/freeswitch.pid
; (...)
```

Is it possible to set the PIDfile on the command line when starting it with the `freeswitch` command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From FreeSWITCH issue [FS-352](https://freeswitch.org/jira/browse/FS-352): PID file location can be configured with the **`-run`** switch:

```
-run [rundir]           -- alternate directory for runtime files
```

See [full list of `freeswitch` command line switches](https://freeswitch.org/confluence/display/FREESWITCH/Command+Line+Switches).